# python - Writing to file with two arrays separated by only a space

Tags: python

I want to print to a file the two arrays in the form below:

```
a1 = [1, 2, 3]
a2 = [9, 9, 9]
```

File looks like

```
1 9
2 9
3 9
```

I currently have the code

```
outstring = zip(Fundvalues, Thirdvalues)
f = open('FFToutput.txt', 'w')
f.write('All values in ohms, dB, dB respectivily\n')
for line in outstring:
    s = str(line) + '\n'
    f.write(s)
f.close()
```

Which does what I want but with brackets and commas in the file obviously.
What is a better method which just puts a space between them, and preferably can be extended to 3 4 or 5 arrays in parallel columns?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
for line in outstring:
    f.write(" ".join(str(x) for x in line) + "\n")
```

The `.join()` method prints each element of the parameter (which is assumed to be an iterable) separated by the string before the `.`. Also, each integer has to be formatted as a string using `str()` before passing to `join()` (which expects each element in its parameter to be a string).